# decrypt p7m file in C# or .NET with privateKey from file

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, private-key, pkcs#7

Hopefully someone can help me with code because I am working on it 3 months without any success. I tried almost anything from internet but nothing does not work.

Problem: I have encrypted file p7m (size 158KB) (it is crypted text). I have certificate in file pfx, under password "a". In this certificate is the public key which is needed to decrypt p7m file.

I need something that will read xyyv.p7m file, decrypt it with public key, and save it as XYZ.xyz

I do not put here any my code to do not confuse you. thanks

Comment: "In this certificate is the public key which is needed to decrypt p7m file" - don't you mean the _private key_?

Comment: This StackOverflow answer might help you:

[Decrypting PKCS#7 encrypted data in C#][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503974/decrypting-pkcs7-encrypted-data-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

A PKCS#7 structure can be **very** messy (and that's actually true for most ASN.1 structures). There's not much specific advice that can be given if we don't know what was used to produce this file.

In general there's code for reading them in [`System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.aspx) but it's easy to create files (valid or invalid) that won't be processed correctly. Even more if they were generated using different tools.

Mono provides classes, inside [`Mono.Security`](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security), to read them. They are very low-level API (with some helpers) so, in theory, they should be able to read anything... as long as you don't mind coding the processing your format itself.

Other libraries, [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) comes to mind, will offer similar (low or high level) API to process PKCS#7 files.