# Is it possible to extract the content of a PKCS#7 signed file using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms?

Tags: c#, cryptography, pkcs#7

I found this post related to pkcs#7 decrypting which suggest that there is no out of the box way to decrypt a signed pkcs#7 file. [Decrypting PKCS#7 encrypted data in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503974/decrypting-pkcs7-encrypted-data-in-c-sharp)

However, I also saw this post and I managed to validate using the SignedCms class. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2006/02/27/539990.aspx

At the end of the post though, extracting the data using **cms.ContentInfo.Content** seems to return the signed file (.zip.p7) instead of the actual content (.zip). Am I missing something here? Using bouncy castle, I was able to get the actual data but would rather not use a third party if it's not necessary.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var encodedFile = File.ReadAllBytes(InPath);

    var signedData = new SignedCms();
    signedData.Decode(encodedFile);
    signedData.CheckSignature(true);
    if (!Verify(signedData))
        throw new Exception("No valid cert was found");

    var trueContent = new CmsSignedData(File.ReadAllBytes(InPath)).SignedContent;

    using (var str = new MemoryStream())
    {
        trueContent.Write(str);
        var zip = new ZipArchive(str, ZipArchiveMode.Read);
        zip.ExtractToDirectory(OutPath);
    }
    //using (var str = new MemoryStream(signedData.ContentInfo.Content))
    //{
    //    var zip = new ZipArchive(str, ZipArchiveMode.Read);
    //    zip.ExtractToDirectory(OutPath);
    //}

}

static bool Verify(SignedCms signedData)
{
    var myCetificates = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    myCetificates.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    var certs = signedData.Certificates;

    return (from X509Certificate2 cert in certs
        select myCetificates.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>()
            .Any(crt => crt.Thumbprint == cert.Thumbprint))
        .Any();

}
```

UPDATE: Will get back with the base64 sample file. Need to come up with one that doesn't contain sensitive information.

UPDATE: Here is the base 64 version of a file I can extract using bouncy castle but not using the ContentInfo.Content property. I've added as a comment on the code how I would extract SignedCms directly.

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

Comment: Could it be that the encrypted CMS structure **is** the content of the signed CMS structure? Because `cms.ContentInfo.Content` should indeed return the content (signing is not encryption).

Comment: I made the file myself signing the .zip to .zip.p7. I've tried using bouncy castle and it returned the stream which I can unzip using ZipArchive. So not sure why the content could not be unzip in a similar manner using SignedCms.

Comment: Can you post a sample file in base64?